# How to declare an extension val for Any type in Kotlin

Tags: android, inheritance, kotlin, extension-methods, dependency-properties

As I know type `Any` in `Kotlin` is similar to `Object` in `java` which by default is implemented by any class we declare. I want to extend the class name into a new `val` `classTag`. Thus,

When I extend a function it works fine,

```
fun Any.getClassTag(): String { return this::class.java.simpleName }
```

But I found compilers error in case when I extend a `val` type.

```
val Any.classTag: String { return this::class.java.simpleName }
```

> Function declaration must have a name

How to deal with that?

Comment: Your issue can be resolved by providing getter method to your variable like : `val Any.classTag: String
    get() {
        return this::class.java.simpleName
    }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have several errors in this one line:

```
Error:(1, 0) Extension property must have accessors or be abstract
Error:(1, 23) Property getter or setter expected
Error:(1, 24) Expecting a top level declaration
Error:(1, 25) Function declaration must have a name
Error:(1, 34) 'this' is not defined in this context
```

This is, because you didn't declare the accessors properly:

```
val Any.classTag: String get() { return this::class.java.simpleName }
```

You only need to add the `get()` accessor just before your block.

Comment: So what are difference between `val Any.classTag: String get() = this::class.java.simpleName` and `val Any.classTag: String get() { return  this::class.java.simpleName}`?

Comment: Actually there's none. The assignment expression for functions is just a shorthand. So even shorter: `val Any.classTag get() = this::class.java.simpleName`. You could even skip the return type then.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating an extension property as if it's a function. The right way to create an extension property is to define the properties' get and set methods. here is what you should've done:

```
val Any.classTag: String
    get() = this::class.java.simpleName
```

[Kotlin Playground Example](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjQwIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsImpzQ29kZSI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiLyoqXG4gKiBZb3UgY2FuIGVkaXQsIHJ1biwgYW5kIHNoYXJlIHRoaXMgY29kZS4gXG4gKiBwbGF5LmtvdGxpbmxhbmcub3JnIFxuICovXG5cbmZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuICAgIHZhbCB4ID0gMTAwZlxuICAgIHByaW50bG4oeC5jbGFzc1RhZylcbn1cblxudmFsIEFueS5jbGFzc1RhZzogU3RyaW5nXG4gZ2V0KCkgPSB0aGlzOjpjbGFzcy5qYXZhLnNpbXBsZU5hbWUifQ==)

Answer (score 2):

> According to [Kotlin Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-properties), Initializers are not allowed for
>   extension properties.

So, only way to provide value to extension property is by explicitly providing **getters/setters**.

In your case, it should be like below :

```
val Any.classTag: String 
    get() { 
        return this::class.java.simpleName
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this[Extension Properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-properties)

> Note that, since extensions do not actually insert members into classes, there's no efficient way for an extension property to have a backing field. This is why initializers are not allowed for extension properties. Their behavior can only be defined by explicitly providing getters/setters.

```
val Any.classTag: String  get() = this::class.java.simpleName
```